# Python - Make API Calls by Looping Through List of URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the Alchemy API to extract keywords/entities for a list of URLs - however as a relative novice to Python - I'm not sure how to do this and the numerous Stack Overflow articles I've read, haven't yielded me any results.

Therefore does anyone know how I can make API calls to a list of URLs either in a list or in a separate txt/csv file?

```
import json
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 \
import Features, EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
  username='Username',
  password='Password',
  version='2017-02-27')

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
url=('https://www.example.com/'),
  features=Features(
    entities=EntitiesOptions(
      emotion=True,
      sentiment=True,
      limit=2),
    keywords=KeywordsOptions(
      emotion=True,
      sentiment=True,
      limit=2)))

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? Hint : The "API call" part is totally irrelevant here - the question is "how do I apply a function working on a single item to a list (or any other iterable) of items"

Answer (score 0):

You can read them line by line from a text file

```
myFile = open("myText.txt", "r")
URL = myFile.readline()
```

Just loop through reading them from the text file.

Comment: Thanks Foster! My only issue now is that it's giving me a status 400 error message. So I'm not sure whether this means I've implemented your suggestion wrong (most likely) or whether I need to add a sleep to this loop in order for IBM Watson not to freak out?